# Git child branch removes updates of parent branch

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, pull-request

Ok, I am having a for my feeling strange problem with git (*using BitBucket*).

I have the following ( example )

- *`development-branch`*

  - *`child-branch`*

Now in the *`child-branch`* I did a lot of rework, but in the same period I also made some bugfixed that where merged by pull requests from another child branch in the *`development-branch`*. Now when i make a pull request from the *`child-branch`* to the *`development-branch`* it wants to remove the fixes made to the *`development-branch`*. But when I want to merge the *`development-branch`* in the *`child-branch`* the fixes made to the *`development-branch`* are not merged to the *`child-branch`*.

Am I doing something wrong in the flow? And is there a way to get this fixed without manualy checking the difference in every single file?

Comment: Rebase child-branch to latest dev-branch maybe? That is, `git checkout child-branch; git rebase development-branch`. Finally, `git push --force` to update the PR (I assume bitbucket supports updating PRs that way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Branch names don't work the way you think they do.

Given what you want to do, you probably want a rebase-oriented work-flow, as [Nikos C. commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534259/git-child-branch-removes-updates-of-parent-branch#comment107092352_60534259).  Remember that rebase means *copy some commits to new-and-improved commits, then move the branch name to use the new-and-improved commits, abandoning the now old-and-lousy commits.*  This means that *everyone* using the rebased branch must be prepared to abandon the old commits.

#### Long

*Branches*, or more precisely, branch *names*, do not have parent/child relationships.  Branch names are merely labels, attached to (or pointing to) specific *commits*.

*Commits*, however, *do* have parent/child relationships.  In particular, the command sequence one uses to make a *new* commit goes like this:

```
git checkout somebranch
[edit various files]
git add file1.ext file2.ext
git commit
```

The `git checkout` step means *select the named branch, and by so doing, select the commit that the branch name selects*.  This *copies the content* of that commit—which in Git, is a complete snapshot of all of your files, stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed format—into both the *index* aka *staging area*, and the *work-tree* or *working tree*.<sup>1</sup>

The edit step, of course, works with those files in the work-tree.

The `git add` step copies the updated work-tree files—where you've made changes—*back into* the index / staging-area, and the last step, `git commit`, makes a new snapshot, with its frozen-for-all-time copies of the file, from the copies that are in the index.  Any files you *didn't* overwrite with `git add` are still the same way they were from your earlier `git checkout`, so the new snapshot has all the files that *aren't* changed, and any updated files that *are* changed, as appropriate.

The new commit, however, is the *child* of the previously-labeled commit.  The previous commit isn't changed—nothing, not even Git itself, can change a commit once it's made—but it now has a child commit.  The child commit, having just been made, records the raw hash ID of its *parent* commit.  So the linkage goes only one way, backwards, from child to parent.  Since the child is a new commit, it gets a new, unique hash ID.

The final, crucial step of `git commit` is that it *writes the new commit hash ID into the branch name*.  That is, the label stops pointing to the previous parent commit and now points to the child commit.

What this means is that we start with a chain of commits, each with a unique (and big and ugly) hash ID, that I'll replace with a single uppercase letter here:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- develop
```

The *name* `develop` currently selects commit `H`.

To this, you add a new name, `feature`, that *also selects commit `H`*:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, feature
```

We now need a way to remember *which branch name you're using*.  To do that, we attach the special name `HEAD` to one branch.  If you `git checkout develop`, we attach the name `HEAD` to `develop`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), feature
```

If you `git checkout feature`, we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, feature (HEAD)
```

Either way, you're *using* commit `H`, but you're doing it through one of two names attached to / pointing to commit `H`.  (Meanwhile commit `H` points back to commit `G` as its parent, and `G` points back to `F`, and so on.)

Now you modify some files in your work-tree, `git add` them to copy them back into the index / staging-area, and `git commit` to make new commit `I`.  Here's what happens if you're on `feature`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
            \
             I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` is still attached to the name `feature`, but `feature` now points to new commit `I`.  New commit `I` points back to commit `H`—where `feature` pointed a moment ago—so that `feature` contains commits up through and including `I`, and `develop` contains commits up through and including `H`.  Note how most commits are still on both branches.

If and when you add commits to `develop`, they just add to `develop`:

```
...--F--G--H--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

There is no parent/child relationship between the names `develop` and `feature`.  They are merely *labels*, identifying specific commits.

This is how branch and tag names in Git work: they identify commits.  The differences between a branch name and a tag name are:

- Branch names *move* over time.  In fact, they move automatically!  Tag names should never move.<sup>2</sup>
- Branch names are *local to one particular repository*.  Other repositories can see them, but when you get commits *from* someone, your Git will copy their *branch* names, like `master`, to your *remote-tracking names*, like `origin/master`.  Tag names are much more global: if they—whoever they are—have a `v1.2`, and you get your commits from them, your Git will probably create your `v1.2` to match.<sup>3</sup>
- And of course, a branch name is a *branch* name, and a tag name is a *tag* name: there are a bunch of smaller knock-on effects, but the two points above are the important differences.

---

<sup>1</sup>The work-tree contains actual files, in the regular ordinary format that you and all the other non-Git programs on your computer can use.  These actual files are not used *by* Git.  It's using the compressed, read-only, Git-only committed files, and using the index / staging area to make *new* commits, as shown above.

<sup>2</sup>It's possible to move a tag, by force or by deleting it and then creating it anew.  However, other software may expect tags *not* to move.  For instance, the Go module system can cache the hash ID of a tag, and if you later move the tag, *not* update.  Moving tags in general is a bad idea: avoid it if you can.

<sup>3</sup>This is under your control, and the default rules here are somewhat complicated, but they amount to you getting their tags if you didn't do anything special.

---

#### Using rebase

Suppose you have this:

```
...--F--G--H--K   <-- develop
            \
             I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

but you want this:

```
                ?--?   <-- feature (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--K   <-- develop
```

You *can't* change existing commits.  Nothing can.  Existing commits `I` and `J` are stuck where they are.  But you *can* **copy** existing commits to new-and-improved versions.  In particular, you can copy commit `I` to a new improved one—we'll call it `I'` to indicate that it is a copy of `I`, although in Git it just gets some big, ugly, random-looking hash ID that has no connection to `I`'s hash ID.  The difference between `I` and `I'` will be:

- `I`'s parent is `H`, but `I'`'s parent will be `K`.
- `I`'s snapshot and `I'`'s snapshot probably won't match, but the *difference* you get by comparing `H`-vs-`I` will be the *same* as the *difference* you get by comparing `K`-vs-`I'`.

Having copied `I` to `I'`, we then want to have Git copy `J` to `J'`.  The result looks like this:

```
                I'-J'
               /
...--F--G--H--K   <-- develop
            \
             I--J
```

Note that I've erased the label `feature` and left out the name `HEAD` entirely, as at this point, we're ready to move `feature` and make `HEAD` be attached to the new, moved `feature`.  The process that does this "build new commits" actually uses what Git calls a *detached HEAD* so right now, the actual situation is:

```
                I'-J'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--K   <-- develop
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

Note that the special name `HEAD` *isn't* attached to any branch name.  That's why this is a *detached HEAD*.  Meanwhile the name `feature` still selects existing commit `J`.

The `git rebase` command's final act, to finish the rebase, is to peel the name `feature` off its existing commit (`J`) and make it point to the same commit that `HEAD` points to (`J'`):

```
                I'-J'  <-- feature, HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--K   <-- develop
            \
             I--J   [abandoned]
```

Having moved the label, rebase re-attaches `HEAD` to the (moved) label, making everything look the way we wanted.  And, since the way Git *finds* commits is to start with the *labels* and work backwards, we can't *see* commits `I` and `J` any more.  All we see is:

```
                I'-J'  <-- feature (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--K   <-- develop
```

If we didn't remember the hash IDs of commits `I` and `J`, we'd think that Git somehow moved the old commits.  It didn't—the old commits are still there, and everyone who has a clone of the repository and who has the old commits, still has the old commits.  We only *see* our *new* ones though.

As Nikos C. noted, if you have an active pull request that's using existing commits `I-J`, you will likely need to use `git push --force` to update the pull request.  You must get whatever Git repository is holding their copies of commits `I` and `J` to abandon theirs in favor of the new and improved `I'-J'` chain.  The precise method of convincing some other Git to switch from the old commits to the new one depends on the controls set up *at* that other Git.  GitHub allow simple `git push --force` to do the trick.

Comment: Wooow thanks for this massive answer. And sorry for commenting so late!

Comment: Wow! great explanation!! I am so lucky found this hard to fine answer :))